# JAVA - Selenium findElement exception

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, xpath

I'am writting small application for automated posting on Facebook. To achive that I copied XPath of "posting input field" from my profile (like in screenshoot):

[image]

This is what has been copied:

```
//*[@id="js_3m"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span/span
```

Now i have created following line of code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"js_3m\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span/span"));
```

Which causes:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="js_3m"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span/span"}
```

Is this approach correct to achieve that?

**Thanks for help :)**

Comment: that is a **very** brittle selector.  you can solve your issue by using an xpath (or css) selector that doesn't traverse down like that.  i'm not opening that page, but you can try `By.cssSelector("div[data-testid$='mentions-input'] span[data-text='true']")`

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed. Use the API.